# C++ Class function with human readable option selector

Tags: c++

I would like to write a function call like this:

```
my_object.myFunction(num_a, num_b, FIRST_OPTION);
```

where the definition of the function is like:

```
MyClass::myFunction(int num_a, int num_b, int option)
{
   if (option == FIRST_OPTION) //do this
   else if (option == SECOND_OPTION) //do that
   // etc.
}
```

Something like calling OpenCV functions, for example `cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2Luv)`, where `img` is a variable and `CV_BGR2Luv` is what I call the human readable option selector.

I tried with some preprocessor definition (`#define FIRST_OPTION 1;`) but it did not work.

Comment: `#define` doesn't use `=`; try `#define FIRST_OPTION 1`

Comment: Please note that the OpenCV pattern is probably inspired by their historical API. In C++ we very much prefer one function to do one thing. If we have a set of similar tasks, we may implement that as an overload set. The real "human friendly selectors" are the function names. It really should have been `cv::BGR2Luv(img,img)` or even `cv::Image img2 {img1, cv::colorspace::Luv}` (as img1 should know its own colorspace, and the ctor overload with an explicit colorspace should know to convert the color spaces)

Comment: Using the solution I'm looking for I can write a useful (for me) object constructor. Where I can not use the function name to understand what the function is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV uses [enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), and passes values as `int`.

You can do something like:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

enum 
{
    OPTION_A,
    OPTION_B,
    OPTION_C
};

void foo(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
    case OPTION_A:
    {
        // do something
        int gfd = 0;
        break;
    }
    case OPTION_B:
    {
        // do something
        break;
    }
    case OPTION_C:
    {
        // do something
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        // ERROR
        // unsupported operation
    }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat3b src(100,100,Vec3b(0,255,0)); // A green image
    Mat3b dst;

    // Custom operation
    foo(src, dst, OPTION_A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since I want call a class function that way, I placed my enum as public, **before** the function which uses it as parameter.